# WPF bind GridViewColumn to different Properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, binding

I have a WPF ControlTemplate that contains a ListView that has its ItemsSource bound to a collection in my class.

Depending on what options the user selects I sometimes want to bind my GridViewColumn to one text value but sometimes I want do display another:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="DescriptionColumn" Header="{DynamicResource MyHeader}" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText1}"/>        
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

What is the best way to go about this? Depending on what data I am displaying I want to either bind to MyText1 or MyText2. How do I make the 'switch'?

Comment: *"Depending on what data I am displaying"* -  how this "depending on" looks like? Is it another property (like two answer below assumes) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is with a multibinding...

```
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="DescriptionColumn" Header="{DynamicResource MyHeader}" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMultiValue}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Which uses the following resources...

```
    <local:MultiValueConverter x:Key="MultiValueConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="TextBlockMultiValue" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Text">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="MyText1"/>
                    <Binding Path="MyText2"/>
                    <Binding Path="Switch"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And the converter is as follows...

```
public class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)values[2] == true)
            return values[0].ToString();
        else
            return values[1].ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So the converter is selecting between one string or another based on a third input to the converter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="DescriptionColumn" Header="{DynamicResource MyHeader}" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding MyText1}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TriggerProperty}" Value="2">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding MyText2}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

In the sample markup above the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` will be bound to "MyText2" when the "TriggerProperty" returns "2".